# SQL Server Snapshot on live DB

Tags: sql, replication, snapshot, transactional-replication

I am in need of some help.I want to reinitialize one of my subscribers with a new snapshot.my previous snapshot i generated was when activity was low on the production database.It took under 2 minutes.

My question is,can i generate a new snapshot during the day when the applications are using the database live? would it lock my tables badly to where transaction wont be followed to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create initial snapshot during the day. 
With transactional replication Snapshot Agent takes locks only during the initial phase of snapshot generation.

Performance impact of this operation depends on current workload of your system. So, if previous snapshot generation took 2 minutes, I think I will take not much more time.